# How do I use a for loop to execute a statement for two variables?

Tags: shell, loops, scripting

```
isql  -U username  -P password  -S servername
```

I want to execute above statement repeatedly for five times, changing username and password each time in a for loop.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

When you don't care that your password can be seen by `ps -ef`, you can do

```
cat credentials.txt
user1 pw1
user2 pw2
user3 pw3
user4 pw4
user5 pw5

while IFS= read -r u p; do
   echo "User $u"
   isql -U "$u" -P "$p" -S servername
done < credentials.txt
```